# Looping through an array and inserting into a table with parent child relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array which looks like

```
     Array
     (
     [438044691:maincategoryone] => Array
     (
      [0] => Array
       (
        [id] => 438044692
        [name] => main category one item one
                    [category] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => Array
                        (
                           [id] => 4380444456
                           [name] => main category one item one - sub
                        )

                    )
       )

      [1] => Array
       (
        [id] => 438044693
        [name] => main category one item two
       )
     )

     [438044701:maincategorytwo] => Array
     (
      [0] => Array
       (
        [id] => 438044702
        [name] => main category two item one
       )

     )

     [438044709:maincategorythree] => Array
     (
      [0] => Array
       (
        [id] => 438044710
        [name] => main category three item one
       )

      [1] => Array
       (
        [id] => 438044711
        [name] => main category three item two
       )

     )
 )
```

How do i loop through this in PHP and store the data in a parent-child-grandchild relationship within the same table (MYSQL).

Also An example query to retrive the data in order (parent-child-grandchild) once inserted would be great.

Hope my question makes sense. If not please excuse me, but i'll be able to give you more information.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have infinite depth or does it stop at grandchild (I mean the grandchildren are leafs)?

Comment: well the max depth will be 3 that is main-sub-subsub. I don't think it'll go any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a reference key to the parent in your mySQL table, like this :

```
CREATE TABLE categories (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32), parent INTEGER)
```

And then in your PHP code, you have a tree model and you read all the items in an id-indexed array, then assemble it into a tree.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
$n = mysql_num_rows($q);
$items = array();

while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $items[$item['id']] = $item;

foreach($items as $item)
    $items[$item['parent']]['category'] = $item;

print_r($items);
```

To read the values from the tree, I would use a recursive function :

```
function add_to_tree($items, $tree_part, $parent) {
    $tree_part['parent'] = $parent;
    $items.push($tree_part);
    foreach($tree_part['categories'] as $child)
        add_to_tree($items, $child, $tree_part['id']);
}
```

Then you just have to create an empty array, fill it and read the values sequencially.

```
$items = array();
add_to_tree($items, $tree);
foreach($items as $item)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories VALUES('{$item['id']}', '{$item['name']}', '{$item['parent']}');
```

Of course you will have to handle special cases like the root object and missing links, which are not supported in this previous code.

Comment: hey thanks for you answer, this could work to retrieve the data but first i must be able to insert the data into the table with the parent-child-grand child relation from the array shown yeah.

Comment: hi well whats the $parent parameter passed to add_to_tree? also the function, will it be returning the $tree_part?.

and ohh i think $items.push will not work in PHP so i'd imagine that to be array_push?.

Comment: well I wrote the code just from my head so there are a few problems. The `add_to_tree` line should be `add_to_tree($items, $tree, 0);` and yes it is array_push :) I made a mistake with javascript syntax. The add_to_tree function (not a very good name, should be add_from_tree) reads recursively the tree and adds the items to the $items array, so there is no need in returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a table with 3 columns `id`, `name`, `parentid`

You can use the PHP [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function to walk through the array and insert the lines as you go (or build an sql query to execute later):

```
    $myArray = ......
    array_walk($myArray , 'insertInDb', null);

    function insertInDb($item, $key, $parent_id) {
        if (is_null($parent_id)) {
            $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO myTable (`id`, `name`, `parentid`) VALUES (%d, "%s", NULL)', $item['id'], $item['name']);
        } else {
           $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO myTable (`id`, `name`, `parentid`) VALUES (%d, "%s", %d)', $item['id'], $item['name'], $parent_id);
        }
        array_walk($item['category'] , 'insertInDb', $item['id']);
    }
```